# How can handle ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE issue in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My AngularJS app uses $http.post() with https urls, when i hit the url i am getting **net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE**

Can anyone help me how can i resolve such issue?

Comment: please share url used in post

Comment: This is something related to headers which server is expecting to validate the request. Check your server log on which we are trying to call POST request

Comment: no error logged, but i am getting the status is 0 and data is null